# setting up for loop in shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I am writing a simple shiny app. I am trying to calculate the CV of several variables shown below.

```
 std1_cv<-reactive({std_data_out_rm() %>% filter(Content == "Std-01") %>% 
select(outlier) %>% sapply(cv, na.rm = TRUE)})
  std2_cv<-reactive({std_data_out_rm() %>% filter(Content == "Std-02") %>% 
select(outlier) %>% sapply(cv, na.rm = TRUE)})
  std3_cv<-reactive({std_data_out_rm() %>% filter(Content == "Std-03") %>% 
select(outlier) %>% sapply(cv, na.rm = TRUE)})
  std4_cv<-reactive({std_data_out_rm() %>% filter(Content == "Std-04") %>% 
select(outlier) %>% sapply(cv, na.rm = TRUE)})
  std5_cv<-reactive({std_data_out_rm() %>% filter(Content == "Std-05") %>% 
select(outlier) %>% sapply(cv, na.rm = TRUE)})
  std6_cv<-reactive({std_data_out_rm() %>% filter(Content == "Std-06") %>% 
select(outlier) %>% sapply(cv, na.rm = TRUE)})
```

I then want to check the condition is met that the CV is less then 0.065. So I created a vector of results.

```
std_cv<-reactive({c(std1_cv(), std2_cv(), std3_cv(), std4_cv(), std5_cv(), std6_cv())})
```

So far so good. I want to design a for loop for each element to create a new logical vector:

```
std_cv3 <- reactive({c()
for(std in std_cv()){
std <- c()
if(as.numeric(std_cv()[1]) < 0.065){
  std_cv3()<-TRUE
}
else{std_cv3()<-FALSE}
}
```

})

Problem is this doesn't seem to work. I get a message:

Error: invalid (NULL) left side of assignment

Frankly I am at a loss this is my first shiny app. I am fairly new to this and I suspect there might be a simple answer to this conundrum which is embarrassing. What's more embarrassing is that I have been at it for the past 48 hours and I've lost all hope. Any suggestions? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could avoid the loop because `<` is vectorized.

```r
std_cv3 <- reactive({
  std_cv() < 0.065
})
```

Comment: Thank you Will. That is very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can not store the values in the reactive expression itself.

```
c() <- 1 # does not work

c <- c()
c <- 1 # does work
```

Something like this should work

```
std_cv3 <- reactive({
  std_cv3 <- std_cv3()

  for(std in std_cv()){
    std <- c()
    if(as.numeric(std_cv()[1]) < 0.065){
      std_cv3<-TRUE
    }
    else{std_cv3<-FALSE}
  }
  std_cv3
})
```

You have to use write std_cv3 in the last line, because the last variable in a reactive expression will be returned.

As just stated in a comment, i would not recommend to use a reactive expression called c(), since c() is reserved as combine function in R and might cause unexpected behaviour. Always use variable like which explain the expected result like "std_result_1"

Comment: I would be extremely careful about using `c` and `c()` as your example for a reactive value/expression, because `c()` is already a function in base `r` and could lead to a number of NAMESPACE collisions.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Your feedback helped a lot:)

Comment: Please do not forget to upvote us, if our answers helped you ;-)